# Set value returns to 0 after a method is called

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-parts

I am creating a connected visual web parts on VS2010.

here is my public partial class ViewEmployeeUserControl : UserControl

```
    #region FindByEmpID
    public void FindEmpByID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewEmployee vwEmp = new ViewEmployee();
        vwEmp.EmpUID = Int32.Parse(txtUID.Text);
```

and here is my public class ViewEmployee : WebPart, EmployeeSchedIF
which uses the EmployeeSchedIF interface

```
    public int _empuid;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control); 
    }

    public int EmpUID
    {
        get{return _empuid;}
        set{_empuid = value;}
    }

    [ConnectionProvider("EmpUID")]
    public EmployeeSchedIF SendUID()
    {
        return (this);
    }

}
```

It works as follows:

1. I will type the Employee ID on the txtUID textbox.
2. After clicking the FindEmpByID button on my user control, I'm setting the value of EMPUID on my Webpart to be equal to the entered value.
3. It will go to this line **vwEmp.EmpUID = Int32.Parse(txtUID.Text)** to determine the value for EMPUID
4. It will then go to **set{_empuid = value;}** and **correctly** sets the value for EMPUID

My problem is this:

1. After correctly setting the value, it will return to this line **vwEmp.EmpUID = Int32.Parse(txtUID.Text)**
2. After that, it will go to the **SendUID** method and **my EMPUID value becomes 0. It did not save the set value.**

What might I missed?

TIA!

Comment: Where are you calling SendUID()? You might not be calling it on vwEmp.

Comment: @GregBahm It is automatically called because it is a provider (imo?)